# Is it possible to mock lifecycle method of Base Activity

Tags: android, testing, mocking

I'm very beginner at mocking and I'm wondering - 
is it possible to mock lifecycle methods?

I have `BaseActivity` and `attachBaseContext` overrided there, is it possible to mock code inside this method for tests?

**Update**. Well, basically inside this method I have

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(Application.myParam() ? updateBaseContext(base) : base);
}
```

And I need not to `updateBaseContext` for my tests.

Comment: Could you please share the code inside the `attachBaseContext` method and information about what you exactly want to mock inside this method?

Comment: @BirjuVachhani, I updated my question, thanks.

Comment: Does it necessary to call `super.attachBaseContext()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only mock methods of mocked objects. To mock this method, your activity must be mocked. But that will not do anything here because you cannot mock a method with void return types. Here, your method `attachBaseContext` has a void return type so It cannot be mocked. which means you cannot define what to when these methods are called. I guess you want to test your activity so you will not mock it.

I'm not sure but this may work for you: What you can do is extend your activity class and override this method but don't call super on it. like this:

```
class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        // do nothing here. don't call super.
    }

}
```

By doing this, when your method `attachBaseContext` will be called, nothing will happen in your test.

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work. Each my activity extends BaseActivity and during test I don't want attachBaseContext to be called. The only way it is working now - I manually disable it before testing.